# Change colour of different objects on click React JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm very new to React JS along with HTML and CSS and have question surrounding the change of seperate element attributes in CSS. I have the following javascript code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import * as FaIcons from "react-icons/fa";
import * as AiIcons from "react-icons/ai";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { SidebarData } from "./SidebarData";
import "../App.css";
import { IconContext } from "react-icons";

function Navbar() {
  const [sidebar, setSidebar] = useState(true);

  const showSidebar = () => setSidebar(sidebar);

  return (
    <>
      <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: "undefined" }}>
        <div className="navbar">
        </div>
        <nav className={sidebar ? "nav-menu active" : "nav-menu"}>
          <div className="app-logo">
            <img src="Src here" alt="logo"/>
          </div>
          <ul className="nav-menu-items" onClick={showSidebar}>
            {SidebarData.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <li key={index} className={item.cName}>
                  <Link to={item.path}>
                    {item.icon}
                    <span>{item.title}</span>
                  </Link>
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </IconContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

that utilises the following CSS:

```
.nav-menu {
  background-color: #181614;
  width: var(--sidebarsize);
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  transition: 850ms;
}

.nav-menu.active {
  left: 0;
  transition: 450ms;
}

.nav-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  height: 120px;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 16px;
  font-family: "Open Sans"; font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav-text a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #6A645E;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.sidebar-icon {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  margin-top: 16px;
}

.nav-menu-items {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}
```

I want to have it such that when I click on a side bar item (the space that both the icon and text take up) the icon changes to it's own color and the text another. For example I click an item "home" with a home icon and title

```
  {
    title: "home",
    path: "/",
    icon: <AiIcons.AiFillHome className="sidebar-icon" />,
    cName: "nav-text",
  }
```

; when clicked the item's icon changes to an orange and it's text to white. How can I achieve this?

*sorry for any code mistakes*

Comment: If it's a navbar do you have a router set up to manage the links? I ask because, for example, `react-router-dom` handles the "active" links for you, and you just need to style them.

Comment: Yes, I understand this and do utilise the links styling, but i'm looking to style the icon and the title text seperately such that when a link is clicked the icon goes orange and the text white

Answer (score 0):

### Do it this way

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import * as FaIcons from "react-icons/fa";
import * as AiIcons from "react-icons/ai";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { SidebarData } from "./SidebarData";
import "../App.css";
import { IconContext } from "react-icons";

function Navbar() {
  const [sidebar, setSidebar] = useState(true);
  const [click, setClick] = useState(false);

  const showSidebar = () => setSidebar(sidebar);

  return (
    <>
      <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: "undefined" }}>
        <div className="navbar">
        </div>
        <nav className={sidebar ? "nav-menu active" : "nav-menu"}>
          <div className="app-logo">
            <img src="Src here" alt="logo"/>
          </div>
          <ul className="nav-menu-items" onClick={showSidebar}>
            {SidebarData.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <li key={index} className={item.cName}>
                  Link to={item.path }>
                    <div style={{color: `${click ? 'orange' : 'someothercolor' }`}}>{item.icon}</div>
                    <span style={{color: `${click ? 'white' : 'someothercolor'}`}}>{item.title}</span>
                  </Link>
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </IconContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: This did not seem to do anything